# Python: Stop watchdog reacting to partially transferred files?

Tags: python, python-2.7, watchdog, python-watchdog

I have previously written a script using python that monitors a windows directory and uploads any new files to a remote server offsite. The intent is to run it at all times and allow users to dump their files there to sync with the cloud directory.

When a file added is large enough that it is not transferred to the local drive all at once, Watchdog "sees" it as it is partially uploaded and tries to upload the partial file, which fails. How can I ensure that these files are "complete" before they are uploaded? Again, I am on Windows, and cannot use anything but Windows to complete this task, or I would have used inotify. Is it even possible to check the "state" of a file in this way on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no easy way to do this.  I think you can put in place something that checks the stats on the directory when it triggers and only actions after a given amount of time that the folder size hasn't changed:

https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog/issues/184

As a side note,  I would check out Apache Nifi.  I have used it with a lot of success and it was pretty easy to get up and running 
https://nifi.apache.org/

Comment: I was afraid I'd have to do something like that. I'll check out nifi, but at this point it may be too late to change. Thanks though.